# CollectionView issue ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview

I am having problems when I do a ReloadData to a CollectionView.

The thing is that I have done a very small project in order to show you what's happening.

(The CollectionView will change the colour background of the cell number 2..but when you do a ReloadData, many cells changed..)

You can find my project here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yy7uen60rc292ir/collectionViewTest.zip?dl=0

Solved!

Thanks for your help!, The thing is I needed to add the function `PrepareForReuse()` where I can "clean" my cells before being reused.

Comment: What is the intended behavior, what is the actual behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reloadData()` reloads the entire datasource for the collectionView. If you are looking to only update a few cells then look into `beginUpdates()` and `endUpdates()`. Here you will be inserting or deleting rows. If you're using Core Data then look into using `NSFetchedResultsController` as this will simplify the entire process and create smooth animations when your data changes.

When you use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` you are reusing those cells. So if you change a background color on one then reuse it you'll see inconsistent changes when reloading the table. Make sure to set the background color on all cells or you'll experience this.

```
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SomeCell") as! UICollectionViewCell
 // This would alternate the colors just to show you what I mean
    indexPath.row % 2 == 0 ? (cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()) : (cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor())
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!, The thing is i dont' understand why if I am changing the colour background of a cell ONLY when indexpath.row == 2...Why If I do a RealoadData() another cells changed their colours?

Comment: Are you reusing cells? Did you set the background on another? You'll need to set the background for both when reusing cells.

Comment: Ok now I understand...the app is reusing my cell in another position so if i have changed its background, then i will see it in another place....I will try to fix it with that info! Thanks!